# How can I solve this error: "Expected identifier"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to draw two images in the UINavigationBar. The first @"cabecera.png" is the background and the second, @"c_portada.png" is an icon that must be over the background. I'm trying to draw the images with drawInRect method but I get the error "Expected Identifier" when I try to draw the second image, why?

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCustomDraw)

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
NSLog(@"Self.topItem.title: %@",self.topItem.title);        

    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cabecera.png"] drawInRect:rect];
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"c_portada.png"] drawInRect:[CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)]]; 
}
@end
```

Comment: Note that this method of drawing in the navigaton bar (category replacement of drawRect) does not work as of iOS 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have invalid leading and trailing square brackets around the `CGRectMake` call**.

This line:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"c_portada.png"] drawInRect:[CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)]];
```

Should be:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"c_portada.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm asleep, I must have a coffe :-)

Answer (score 3):

CGRectMake is not an objective-c function. It's actually a c function and hence doesn't need the square brackets that are specific to objective-c calls only.

So the correct answer would be:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"c_portada.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"c_portada.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
```

You have an extra [ before CGRectMake.

Comment: You're still one bracket off :)